# Editing wait activities in paused journeys

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Hello all so I have a paused journey because they wanted to change the wait period till a bit later in the day.  After pausing I realize that I cannot edit the wait activity.

If I resume the journey AFTER the wait activity will the contacts be sent the email immediately upon activation?  So the wait is until 12:30 but now they want it out at 4:30 - if I activate at 4:30 will it send to all contacts immedately?

[image]

Comment: More details here = https://sfmc.in/wait.html

Answer (score 2):

You can extend or not extend the wait time of all Wait by Duration activities on that journey by the duration of the journey’s pause. If you don’t extend the wait time and the wait expires during a pause, the contact is processed after the journey resumes. Your selection for this option applies to all Wait by Duration activities on the paused journey (or all versions of the journey). This configuration option is only available for Wait by Duration activities. The wait time for Wait by Attribute and Wait for Date isn’t extended by default.

The system processes Wait Until activities, but the contact doesn’t go to the next activity until the journey resumes.

Source - [Journey Pause](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_pause.htm&type=5)